# Google Pie chart not displaying in IE <= 8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, web-applications, emulation, google-visualization

I need to execute this .php file for different IE versions but the following errors appear when I emulate to:

- IE 8:"gvjs_VL" is undefined.
- IE <8: "JSON" is undefined.

I have tried also to use json2 when the IE version was <= 8 but it did not solve the issue. 
What could be happening?

Thank you in advance. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
$chartData = array(array("Area" , "Number of people"),
                   array("A"    , 5000),
                   array("B"    , 8000),
                   array("C"    , 400),
                   array("D"    , 40000),
                   array("E"    , 1000),
                   array("F"    , 1400 ));  
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="chartContainer">
    <div id="piechart" class="piechart">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load google charts
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Draw the chart and set the chart values
        function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( <?php echo json_encode($chartData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);

          // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
          var options = {fontName:'Arial', legend:{position: 'labeled', maxLines:15, alignment:'start'}, 
                         textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 30}, 
                         pieHole: 0.4, sliceVisibilityThreshold:0.0,
                         chartArea: {   
                                     width: "100%",
                                     top: "0%",
                                     left: "0%"},

                         };

          // Display the chart inside the div> element with id="piechart"
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#troubleshooting): `Why do my charts work in some browsers but not all? [...] With Google Charts, there are sometimes problems in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier`. Even Microsoft does not support IE8 anymore.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't even bother to support IE10 these days. Google certainly won't. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support

Comment: I thought it was related to the json which is not included in old versions of IE. Thank you so much for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to run your PHP code so I try to test the Google Charts Sample with JS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 8],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['TV', 4],
  ['Gym', 2],
  ['Sleep', 8]
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'My Average Day', 'width':550, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE browser:

[image]

If you check the source code then you can notice that Google Charts using **SVG** in their charts. **SVG** is not supported in IE <= 8.

[image]

Reference:

[SVG (basic support)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)

This can be the one of the reason that it is not working in IE <=8 versions.

At present, IE 8 and earlier versions are not supported. It is recommended to upgrade to IE 11 browser. It can help to avoid this issue.

Comment: My apologies, I really do not know why you are not able to run it as I basically uploaded as I have it (and works for me). Either way, thank you so much for your answer and advice!